# Miranda or Fulton for algebraic perspective on Riemann surface

Tags: book-recommendation, riemann-surfaces

I have read Donaldson, Riemann surface and it gives a nice (differential) geometric treatment for it. Now I want to supplement it by an algebraic perspective, and I'm told I should read either Fulton or Miranda. Which one should I read, and what's the benefit of using one over the other ? I'd prefer concrete examples and geometric exposition (as in, nice pictures) any day over some category theoretic nonsense.

Comment: [This MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313254/references-for-riemann-surfaces) has a good survey including the books by Fulton and Miranda. The comments on Fulton are positive.

Comment: I feel that Fulton is more concrete and down-to-earth, but I think if you've read Donaldson then you're certainly ready to handle Miranda. I would recommend that you read both at first and then decide for yourself, since there is some sense the two books provide different things. Fulton develops a foundational theory upon a foundation of pretty basic abstract algebra, while Miranda assumes you have a bit more geometric sophistication (for example, you have seen Stokes on manifolds) and tries to use the subject of Riemann surfaces to lift you to algebraic ideas applicable in higher dimensions.